# Lock location of slider of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have grid, where I have a lot of records.

There is operation like selecting row, and in other window I do some things with this row.

So i have a delegate to the second window.

When delegate is fired I'm refreshing my grid.

I don't know how to lock slider to be in place, where I select this old record.

So, if this record wa 43th, now I want to select 43th row (it could be another record, but the same position).

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your delegate you could take a look into the `CurrentRow` property of your master `DataGridView`. With this informations do a call to [`DataGridView.Rows.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.indexof.aspx) and use this index in your slave Grid [`SetSelectedRowCore()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.setselectedrowcore.aspx) to set the wanted index.

Answer (score 0):

It is what I wanted:

myDataGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.RowIndex;